# Connecting to a local HTTP socket in Haskell

Tags: sockets, http, haskell

What is the best way to connect to a local socket in Haskell?

Once the connection is made HTTP is used to communicate (I want to connect to the local Docker socket)

wreq and http-client seem to deal only with URLs rather than sockets.

On the command line I can use `curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json` but I can't find the equivalent of `--unix-socket` in the curl package on hackage.

Comment: I think you are talking about berkeley sockets. An example client for that https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/blob/master/example/client.hs is available through the websockets package.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible with [http-client](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client). You should [create](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:newManager) `Manager` with [custom hook](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.27/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:managerRawConnection) to make a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps more primitive option is to use second-transfer, there is a functional [HTTP/1.1 request-maker](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/second-transfer-0.10.0.1/docs/SecondTransfer-Http1-Proxy.html#v:ioProxyToConnection) inside:

```
...
import Data.Conduit
import SecondTransfer.Http1.Proxy  (ioProxyToConnection)
import SecondTransfer.Http1.Types
import Control.Lens

main = 
  do
    ...
    -- Somehow get a socket from the networking package, i.e, with type 
    -- Network.Socket.Socket . AF_UNIX sockets are OK, and then wrap it 
    -- in a set of I/O callbacks:
    io_callbacks <- handshake =<< socketIOCallbacks my_socket

    -- Puts and receives the data for the http request, get the results. Only needs the  
    -- headers that will be sent over the tube, and the streaming contents
    -- with request data.
    let 
        request :: HttpResponse IO
        request = HttpRequest [("host", 
                               "http://127.0.0.1:8080"), 
                          ...]
                          (yield "")

    -- Perform the request, get the response.
    response <- ioProxyToConnection io_callbacks request

    -- Use the lens interface to access the headers:
    putStrLn . show $ response ^. headers_Rp

    -- You can consume a streaming response using response ^. body_Rp
```